# Passing boolean in for Enum parameter type compiles and runs?

Tags: vb.net, function, enums, boolean

I have an Enum thus:

```
Enum CurrentPeriodType
   CurrentDate
   Sales
   Utilization
End Enum
```

I have a function thus:

```
Private Sub PopulateDDLPeriods(currentPeriodType As CurrentPeriodType)

...

End Sub
```

I make a function call thus:

```
PopulateDDLPeriods(False)
```

I run it, it compiles and runs, and I step through the code and indeed it is going from the function call into the function that expects an ENUM. I thought maybe I had an overload...but I actually stepped through the code and it went into the ENUM parameter-typed function...

HUH?

Comment: What's your `Option Strict` setting?

Comment: AakashM and APrough together sum up the situation. VB will perform implicit data-type conversions behind the scenes whenever it can - unless you make use of the `Option Strict On` directive at the start of your code. `Option Strict On` will disable implicit data-type conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible because your [`Option Strict`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) is off.  If you do not like the behavior that you see, turn it on.  However, doing so will also imply `Option Explicit` forcing you to declare all variables, and *also* to specify the data type of your `Enum` which is how we knew you had it off.

In your case, the internal value of `CurrentDate` is `0`.  It is therefore not very surprising (considering that `Option Strict` is off) that `False` can convert to 0 and also to the enum.

What could be more surprising is that your code will compile and run even after you change it as follows:

```
Enum CurrentPeriodType
   CurrentDate = 1
   Sales = 2
   Utilization = 3
End Enum
```

or alternatively, if you start passing in `True` (which converts to -1).

As you can see, .NET enums are just "partly enumerated" synonyms for their respective underlying data types and you can get in any value of such a data type if you try just a little.

Answer (score 1):

First off, why would you make the function use an Enum, but supply a boolean value to it?

What is happening is that the boolean value is evaluating as a 0, giving you the Sales Enum value.  If you switch the parameter in your function call to True, it will actually evaluate as a -1 from the Enum.

One thing that would probably help in this situation is to explicitly add in the values for the enum (CurrentDate = 0, Sales = 1, etc).  When you call that function, make sure your parameter is a valid Enum instead of supplying a variable of a different type.